# xcopy a maven .m2\repository\* folder to another computer?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm using eclipse 3.7 and my local maven repository has a bunch of jars in it.  I tried to build the project on another computer that is on a different network and has *.jar download restrictions.  I will not be able to get the restrictions lifted.   Here is an example error:

e.g. Access denied to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.jar Error code 403, Forbidden (Content blocked ...)

It would be very nice if I could simply copy my .m2\repository\ folder into the .m2\repository\ on the other computer--both are running windows.  I really don't want to manually install 100s of jars on the other computer.

Is xcopy for .m2\repository\ supported?

Comment: You can, of course, copy the `.m2/repository` folder to another storage device as it's just another folder in the filesystem. Not sure what you mean by `xcopy` here, though.

Comment: Thanks.  to be clear I intend to copy my .m2/repository to a new computer and also into a coworkers .md/repository folder so that we can both work offline on those computers.  FYI: xcopy is shorthand for "Copy all files and directories, including subdirectories"  I should have made that part more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can copy the `.m2/repository` folder to any other location/storage device you want.

Maven only needs to know the path to the local repository (by default it's in `%USER_HOME%/.m2/repository`). You can change that path in Maven's `settings.xml` (see [settings reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)) if you decide to keep the artifacts in a different location.

Comment: That was an easy enough answer :)  I'm glad it ended up being that simple.